# Убрать картинку и вставить в другом месте JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку когда на другом месте появляется картинка, исчезала предыдущая. То есть должно быть всего одна картинка, я буду использовать setInterval.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let collection = document.querySelectorAll('.photo');
let url = 'https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg';

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  rndImage();
});

for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  const item = collection[i];
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (item.childElementCount) {
      item.firstChild.remove();
      rndImage();
    }
  });
}

function rndImage() {
  let rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(collection.length));
  if (collection[rnd].childElementCount) return false;
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = url;
  collection[rnd].appendChild(img);
};
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.photo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #272727;
  margin: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: background .2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photo:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.photo img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<button>Start</button>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А задумка в том, чтобы картинка сама быстро перепрыгивала в случайные клетки, и нужно было "поймать" её кликом?)

Comment: Ну да типо того

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> чтобы ... исчезала предыдущая

```
function rndImage() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.photo img')].forEach(
    item => item.parentNode.removeChild(item)
  );

  // ...
}
```

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let collection = document.querySelectorAll('.photo');
let url = 'https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg';

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  rndImage();
});

for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  const item = collection[i];
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    rndImage();
  });
}

function rndImage() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.photo img')].forEach(
    item => item.parentNode.removeChild(item)
  );

  let rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(collection.length));
  if (collection[rnd].childElementCount) return false;
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = url;
  collection[rnd].appendChild(img);
};
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.photo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #272727;
  margin: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: background .2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photo:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.photo img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<button>Start</button>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не понял суть. .

Comment: @Kardinal Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: Я только изучаю JS, поэтому возникают такие сложности. Не могли бы подсказать как именно нужно написать данный код ?

Comment: @Kardinal Как показано, его надо вставить в начало функции `rndImage`.

Comment: вставляю , не сработает

Comment: @Kardinal "не сработает" - объясните, что Вы ожидаете и что происходит

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100469/discussion-between-kardinal-and-igor).

Answer (score 3):

Хотел просто ответить, по инерции написал игрушку)))

Чем дальше - тем больше очков даётся за клик. Больше 1000 не получалось набрать)

Можно проиграть только если кликнуть на котика, или на пустую ячейку.

[( JsFiddle )](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/h0Logxze/)

```js
(function(){

let chebu = 'https://gyazo.com/f850be7e9fc91aa2c8cb844603ea1e10.png';
let kitty = 'https://gyazo.com/7d236d0d4a315b0fa177c1697a8af27c.png';
let kittyChance = 0.2;
let tick = 2000; // Время переключения картинки (будет уменьшаться)
let timeout = null;
let lastSpawnIndex; // Номер блока, где в последний раз появилась картинка

let img = document.createElement('img'); // Одна картинка, будет перемещаться appendChild
    img.draggable = false; // Чтобы при клике картинка не "захватывалась".

let score = 0;

let gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery');
let start = document.getElementById('start');
let displayScore = document.getElementById('display-score');
let photo = document.querySelectorAll('.photo');
let len = photo.length;

start.onclick = function(){
  clearTimeout( timeout );
  handleImageSpawn();
}

for (let i = 0; i < photo.length; i++) {
  photo[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    // Клик происходит, когда кнопку мышки уже отпустили.
    // А mousedown срабатывает как только нажали. Чтобы легче игралось.
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    let image = this.children[0];
    if (!image || image.src == kitty) {
      // Если картинки не оказалось или кликнули на котика.
      endGame();
      return;
    }
    
    updateScore();
    handleImageSpawn();
  });
}

function handleImageSpawn() {
  tick = (tick <= 500) ? 500 : tick * 0.99;
  // Время каждый раз будет уменьшаться, до 0,5 секунды.
  
  let color = new Array(3).fill((tick - 500) / 6).join();
  // Затемнение фона по мере прогресса.
  gallery.style.backgroundColor = `RGB(${color})`;

  let spawnIndex = newRandIndex(len, lastSpawnIndex);

  img.src = chebu;
  if ( tryProbability(kittyChance) ) {
    setTimeout(() => img.src = kitty, 150);
    // Подстава. Иногда чебурашка будет заменяться на котика,
    // через 150 миллисекунд после появления.
  }

  photo[spawnIndex].appendChild(img);
  lastSpawnIndex = spawnIndex;

  timeout = setTimeout(handleImageSpawn, tick);
  // Если всё прошло путем - функция вызывает сама себя после tick миллисекунд.
}

function newRandIndex(length, prev) {
  let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
  while (n == prev) {
    // Чтобы обновленный индекс не совпадал с предыдущим
    n = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
  }
  return n;
}

function tryProbability(chance) {
  return Math.random() < chance;
}

function endGame() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  tick = 2000;
  alert("Game Over.\n\nScore: " + score);
  displayScore.textContent = score = 0;
}

function updateScore() {
  score = Math.round(score + 4000000 / Math.pow(tick, 1.9));
  // Вначале клик дает +2 очка ( tick == 2000 )
  // А к концу будет +30 очков ( tick == 500 )
  displayScore.textContent = score;
}

})();
```

```css
body {
  user-select: none;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
}

.photo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #272727;
  margin: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: background 0.2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photo:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.photo img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button> Score: <span id="display-score">0</span>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нажал на "Start" несколько раз, и случилось страшное. Но волнует не это, а вопрос... где я могу получить выигрыш?))) Если серьезно, то за старания - точно огромный плюс.

Answer (score 2):

Метод `appendChild()` не копирует, а *переносит* элемент - так что, в удалении нет необходимости (создание новых элементов при каждом клике так же не требуется, в данном случае).

Я немножко отрефакторил код, чтобы было проще видеть суть:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button'),
      container = document.querySelector('.gallery'),
      collection = container.querySelectorAll('.photo'),
      img = document.createElement('img');
let url = 'https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg';
img.src = url;

container.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('.photo img'))
    rndImage();
});
button.addEventListener('click', rndImage);

function rndImage() {
  let rnd;
  do {
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * collection.length);
  } while (collection[rnd].childElementCount);
  collection[rnd].appendChild(img);
};
```

```css
.gallery { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; user-select: none; }
.photo { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #272727; margin: 15px; box-sizing: border-box; transition: background .2s ease; cursor: pointer; }
.photo:hover { background: #ccc; }
.photo img { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; }
```

```html
<button>Start</button>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
</div>
```